# Can't break block in Minecraft for iPhone

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I used to play Minecraft PE a lot and I've re-downloaded it on my brand new iPhone 6S for old times sake. Every other button is working fine, but blocks don't highlight when I touch them, and my character's arm swipes once and then holds still, even if I hold down on the block.

I've messed around in the settings, with sensitivity, controls, etc. It says you need to hold down on a block when you want to break it, but that's just not working. I am on survival mode, not adventure, so I know that's not it. I haven't seen anyone else with this problem on mobile.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: We don't edit questions with "closed" in them when they are no longer relevant. you can either self answer with your solution or delete the question yourself

Comment: @Archer - I have added a community wiki answer for now. If you wish to add your own answer and earn some reputation points for it, do so and I will remove the wiki one :).

Answer (score 2):

From the OP, posted in the question body:

---

> I deleted and redownloaded the app, and now it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

you either:
1. don't have permission to edit blocks
2. are too far away from the block
3. accidentally set it to a different control